# Magento Soap API Customer Edit Password Change

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I'm working with magento soap api v1 and v2. I want to edit my customer details using API. [Customer Update](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.update.html) api is updating all the data like first name , lastname, email, but password field is not getting updated. It is same with both version of API.

Here is my code.

```
    function customerEdit(){
$api_user = 'magento';
 $api_pwd = 123456;
    
    
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
            $session = $client->login($api_user, $api_pwd);
    
           
         $result = $client->customerCustomerUpdate($session, '1', array('email' => 'vikky@gmail.com', 'firstname' => 'vikky', 'lastname' => 'abcds', 'password' => '123456', 'website_id' => 1, 'store_id' => 1, 'group_id' => 1));
    
            echo $result;
         var_dump ($result);
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
```

password does not have any restrictions like uppercase lowercase symbols.
all the api credentials are correct and active. Dont know where i'm going wrong please help.

Comment: How do you know the PW field is not getting updated?

Comment: im trying to login with the new password its  not getting logged in, but when i enter the old password its getting logged in successfully

Comment: Are the other fields updating?

Comment: yes other fields like first name last name and email are getting updated

Comment: It looks correct. I would suggest tracing the code.